# .NET Deployment (ClickOnce or MSI) Client Settings/Parameters

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I've created a windows forms application. I have a requirement of storing some information (in the Registry, Isolated Storage or other serialization method) like ClientID which is a GUID generated from a registration form before the user can download the installation package which is currently ClickOnce deployed. The application is run offline so adding querystring parameters is not an option based on some articles i've read. I thought creating a module to modify the config.deploy file before the client downloads the setup but it might cause some issues when multiple users simultaneously download the app. I'm also looking at having the User enter an email address or any login info at the app's first run, so the necessary info can be downloaded from the web server and stored in the client's machine but i'm not yet sure if they'll approve this method.

I hope I've written this clear enough so I can get some answers soon enough. Any comments/suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a pure ClickOnce app that had a registration process to really use it.  You could start the app just fine with no registration but to get into the meat of the app you had to fill out a small form with the data stored in our database.  The app stored the registration data (less the password) in Isolated Storage.

Feel free to post questions in the comments and I'll try to follow up.

Comment: Registration is required in this app and it should happen in a webpage which redirects to the download page after the user successfully registered. The server generates the ClientID which will then be stored in the client machine for upload/posting of data to the web server.

Comment: Your registration process could generate a code that the user has to enter into the app before it will work (like a "Please enter the registration code:" prompt).  It sounds like you already have the storage handled.